# Using pseudo selectors with hidden elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to maintain odd/even list item styling, when some list items are hidden with a filter (using the `hidden` attribute).

I thought I could achieve it like this:

```
li:not([hidden]):nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: yellow;
}
li:not([hidden]):nth-of-type(even) {
    background: green;
}
```

but when I hide list item #2, list item #3 stays 'odd'. I thought it would become even, since it is now the second list item without a 'hidden attribute:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li> // yellow
    <li hidden>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li> // yellow but should be green?
    ..
</ul>
```

Is it possible with `pseudo selectors/not:()` to do the above? Or is `hidden` just not observed with `odd/even`?

Thanks

Neil

Comment: `hidden` is a global HTML5 attribute so can be used on all elements. But take your point re `nth-of-type`, thanks

Comment: Oops, you're right, sorry. Here is an upvote to make up.